# Django list data from dfiferent models in List View with correct ordering

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

Heys guys.. I am making a Django project which is a simple clone of Twitter.. Got the idea from Justin Mitchell's Udemy course..
So i implemented a Tweet model  and a Retweet model which has ForeignKey to the original Tweet and the User..
The thing is that in the homepage i want both the Tweets and Retweets to show and in the order they were created..
I am using Django Rest Framework for the CRUD functionality of Tweet using ModelViewSet
Any idea on how i achieve that using Rest Framework or if that isn't possible could you please give me some other idea.. 
Thank you in advance..

**models.py**

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
   content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   class Meta:
       ordering = "-created_on", "content", "user",

   def __str__(self):
       return self.content

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse("tweet_api:tweet-detail", args=[self.id])


class Retweet(models.Model):
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="retweet")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = "-created_on", "user",

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet.content
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    created_on = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    date_display = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Tweet
        fields = "id", "content", "created_on", "date_display", "user",

    def get_created_on(self, obj):
        return obj.created_on.strftime("%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y")

    def get_date_display(self, obj):
        obj_date = obj.created_on
        days = (timezone.datetime.now() - obj_date).days
        if days > 0:
            return obj_date.strftime("%d %b")
        else:
            return naturaltime(obj_date)

class RetweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tweet = TweetSerializer()
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    date_display = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Retweet
        fields = "id", "tweet", "user", "created_on", "date_display",

    def get_date_display(self, obj):
        obj_date = obj.created_on
        days = (timezone.datetime.now() - obj_date).days
        if days > 0:
            return obj_date.strftime("%d %b")
        else:
            return naturaltime(obj_date)
```

**views.py**

```
class TweetViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.TweetSerializer
    queryset = models.Tweet.objects.all()
    pagination_class = DefaultPagination
    filter_backends = filters.SearchFilter,
    search_fields = "content", "user__username", "user__first_name", "user__last_name",

    def perform_create(self, serialiazer):
        return serialiazer.save(user=self.request.user)


class RetweetViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.RetweetSerializer
    queryset = models.Retweet.objects.all()
    pagination_class = DefaultPagination
    filter_backends = filters.SearchFilter,
    search_fields = "tweet__content", "user__username", "user__first_name", "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tweet and Retweet data reside on completely different models, what you want to do is not simple with your current model structure. To combine them in a single view, you'd need to override many things on ViewSet, and do the operations like sorting in-memory, which would not be scalable. One possible solution could be to use model inheritance, have a base model for both Tweet and Retweet, and build your serialzier and view set on that model. A model structure like the following could be used:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """
    Base model for user posts
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Tweet(Post):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Retweet(Post):
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="retweet")
```

With these models in-place, you can create a **PostSerializer** and **PostViewSet**, and use these only for listing posts, you can keep using **Tweet** and **Retweet** views and serializers for creating and updating.

Comment: It worked.. Thank you.. Could you please tell me some resources where i could learn more on this and other great stuff on Django.. It will really be helpfull

Comment: You're welcome. Official django docs are a very good source of info in general. This is the link to model inheritance docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance And this is a link to a listing page for all docs content: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/contents/